# Check whether a file is open in Matlab

Tags: file, matlab, ubuntu, filesystems

I'm downloading some big files(2GB) and also I'm running a Matlab script which is unpacking the data and do some simulation, this script run as a cronjob, and sometimes the cronjob is starting before the download has finished. How can I check in Matlab whether the file is still open (downloading and writing)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use a `.lock` file...

Your cronjob should create a `.lock` file before starting downloading, and remove after it's done.

Your matlab script can check if the `.lock` file is there, to know if the file is being used by the cronjob.

Comment: So, instead of manually downloading it, make a script that create the .lock file, download, and then remove it.

Answer (score 2):

While you could go spelunking in `/proc/*/fds` to find the file, such a solution would be impractical, error-prone, and require the downloader and the matlab script to be running as the same user.

Instead of that, just download to a temporary directory or file and *m*o*v*e the file once the download has finished.